# User's data (profile) updates only after logout

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple database update query:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET user_name = '$name', user_email = '$email', user_phone = '$phone', user_gender = '$gender', user_addr = '$address', user_about = '$about' WHERE id = '$id' ";

$result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

The query is successfully executed. But, the change can not be seen before I logout and login again. Can it be a due to the current $_SESSION? How can I fixed this?

Comment: If your user data is stored in a `$_SESSION`, then after the successful update you need to update each `$_SESSION` value.

Comment: Thank you @Sean I just fixed it :D